# Forbidden to access PhpMyAdmin in VPS of Ubuntu,Apache and Mysql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, rails

I get this error through access phpmyadmin in my vps.
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 188.165.168.89 Port 1091

I config ruby on rails with Apache(:1091) and Passenger then I wanted phpmyadmin for managing database. So, I installed mysql,php and phpmyadmin
But I cannot access my phpmyadmin with this url.

http://188.165.168.89:1091/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

you should check through the absolute path of phpmyadmin for permissions. my clue is that in some level the web server has no access to a folder, and therefore isn't able to execute your admin interface.

you could try something like the following:

```
chgrp -R <your webserver group (most likely www-data)> /path/to/phpmyadmin

# Add execute rights on the folders in order to 
# allow the web-server to access you files
find /path/to/phpmyadmin -type d -exec chmod g+x {} +

# then, allow the web-server to read the files in the path
find /path/to/phpmyadmin -type f -exec chmod g+r {} +
```

You shouldn't have any issues after that anymore.

If the problem still exists after this, you should try this a folder level lower, without the `-R` flags

```
chgrp www-data /path/to
chmod g+x /path/to
```

I hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go to your phpMyAdmin.conf and edit it to require your computers IP.

```
 Require ip your.pcs.ip.address
```

Right now phpMyAdmin may be configured to only allow localhost access.